# Filtering out null values in a linq search

Tags: database, linq, linq-to-sql

Im building a book library which handles Books and Journals.
I have a winform where the user enters some parameters to search on the library DB. i do not know which value he selects to insert.

For example:

```
public abstract class Item : IComparer, IEnumerable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

this is my base class. when a user can insert to search by name (which translates into book name).
the UI has many options to search by, and basiclly includes almost all of the fields that a book contains.

What i need to do is filter out only the fields that the user inserted, pass them to my DAL so he can perform the search using a LINQ query on ENTITY framework mapped DB.

this is my search so far:

```
public List<Books> SelectBookFromDB(Item itemType)
{
    BookVO book = itemType as BookVO;
    var result = myEntities.Books.Where(x =>
                                        x.Author == book.Author &&
                                        x.Discount == book.Discount &&
                                        x.Name == book.Name &&
                                        x.Publisher == book.Publisher).ToList();              
    return result;
}
```

problem is, im searching for some values that may be null. that way, my searches always come up empty :(
i have no clue how to proceed. would love some help.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more then one step to generate the query:

```
var result = myEntities.Books;

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(book.Author) == false)
{
  result = result.Where(x => x.Author == book.Author);
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(book.Name) == false)
{
  result = result.Where(x => x.Name == book.Name);
}

...And so on.

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Item class so that every type is properly nullable:

```
public abstract class Item : IComparer, IEnumerable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public double? Discount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

This allows every property to clearly demarcate when it has a value and when it doesn't. What if someone wants to search for all books which are regular price (meaning Discount == 0)?

Then, you can simply add null checking to your results query:

```
var result = myEntities.Books.Where(x =>
   (book.Author == null || x.Author == book.Author) &&
   (book.Discount == null || x.Discount == book.Discount) &&
   (book.Name == null || x.Name == book.Name) &&
   (book.Publisher == null || x.Publisher == book.Publisher)).ToList();
```